# FlexLayout, components does not use full space

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

I am trying to use flex Layout to align my cards on my dashboard. But they are not using the covering the rest of the space.

I am not able to understand why it is happening.
Right my design looks like this

[image]
I want the card to use full space.
Along with the bottom of the cards aligned to each other.

I went through the documentation, but did'nt find anything useful which can set the `width: 100%`

I tried `flex="0 0 100%"`, but it does'nt occupy width, it increases the height.
What should i do to align cards.

I am using flexLayout inside a `mat-drawer-content`

Here is the full code:

```html
<app-toolbar (open)="onOpen()" >  
</app-toolbar>      
 <mat-drawer-container> 
  
  <mat-drawer #drawer mode="over" color="accent" [opened]="flag">          
    <mat-list>
      <mat-list-item >Home </mat-list-item>
      <mat-list-item >List Employees</mat-list-item>
      <mat-list-item >Insights</mat-list-item>
      <mat-list-item >Time Tracker </mat-list-item>
    </mat-list>          
  </mat-drawer>

  <mat-drawer-content>
    <!-- <button type="button" style="margin: auto;" mat-button (click)="drawer.toggle()"> Toggle</button>  -->
    <div fxLayout="column">
      <mat-card>
        <mat-card-header>
          <mat-card-title>
            <h3 color="accent">Quick Links</h3>
            <mat-divider></mat-divider>
          </mat-card-title>      
        </mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-content>   
          <div class="example-button-row">
            <button mat-raised-button>Basic</button>
            <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Add Employees</button>
            <button mat-raised-button color="primary">View Employees</button>
            <button mat-raised-button color="accent">Primary</button>
            <button mat-raised-button color="accent">Primary</button>
            <button mat-raised-button color="accent">Primary</button>
            <button mat-raised-button color="accent">Primary</button>
            <button mat-raised-button color="accent">Primary</button>
            <button mat-raised-button color="accent">Primary</button>
            <!-- <button mat-raised-button color="accent">Primary</button>
            <button mat-raised-button color="accent">Primary</button>
            <button mat-raised-button color="accent">Accent</button>           
            <button mat-raised-button color="accent">Accent</button>                       
            <button mat-raised-button color="accent">Basic</button> -->
          </div>
        </mat-card-content>    
      </mat-card>
    </div>
    <div style="padding-top: 10px;">
    </div>
    <div  fxLayout="row"  fxLayoutGap="10px" fxLayoutAlign=" flex-start stretch">
      <div fxLayout="column"  fxLayoutGap="10px" fxFlex="1 1 30%">
        <!-- <div fxFlex="20" flex> -->
          <mat-card>     
            <mat-card-header>
              <mat-card-title>
                Quick Links
              </mat-card-title>      
            </mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-content>                    
              <mat-list>
                <mat-list-item>Item 1</mat-list-item>
                <mat-divider></mat-divider>
                <mat-list-item>Item 2</mat-list-item>              
              </mat-list>
            </mat-card-content>      
          </mat-card>
        <!-- </div>  -->
        <div fxFlex="60" flex>
          <mat-card>     
            <mat-card-header>
              <mat-card-title>Important Notifications</mat-card-title>
            </mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-content>                     
              <mat-list>
                <mat-list-item>Item 1</mat-list-item>
                <mat-divider></mat-divider>
                <mat-list-item>Item 2</mat-list-item>
                
              </mat-list>
            </mat-card-content>            
          </mat-card>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div  fxLayout="column" fxFlex="1 1 40%" >     
        <mat-card>     
          <mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-title>
              Important Notifications 
              <!-- 
            </mat-card-title>
          </mat-card-header>
          <mat-card-content>                     
            <mat-list>
              <mat-list-item>Item 1</mat-list-item>
              <mat-divider></mat-divider>
              <mat-list-item>Item 2</mat-list-item>
              <mat-divider></mat-divider>
              <mat-list-item>Item 3</mat-list-item>            
              <mat-divider></mat-divider>
              <mat-list-item>Item 3</mat-list-item>            
              <mat-divider></mat-divider>
              <mat-list-item>Item 3</mat-list-item>            

            </mat-list>
                    
          </mat-card-content>              
        </mat-card>    
      </div>
      <div  fxLayout="column"  fxFlex="1 1 30%">    
          <mat-card>     
            <mat-card-header>
              <mat-card-title>
                Important Notifications
              </mat-card-title>
            </mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-content>              
              <mat-list>
                <mat-list-item>Item 1</mat-list-item>
                <mat-divider></mat-divider>
                <mat-list-item>Item 2</mat-list-item>
                <mat-divider></mat-divider>
                <mat-list-item>Item 3</mat-list-item>            
              </mat-list>
              <mat-list>
                <mat-list-item>Item 1</mat-list-item>
                <mat-divider></mat-divider>
                <mat-list-item>Item 2</mat-list-item>
              </mat-list>            
            </mat-card-content>      
          </mat-card>    
      </div>
    </div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>   
  </mat-drawer-content>  

  
</mat-drawer-container>
```

A stackblitz example of the solution would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Providing your problem in a stackblitz would also be much appreciated

Comment: Its tough for me :p. I am a newbie.
Atleast share some useful piece of code... without stackblitz?